# Cannot open existing package and msdb from integration system?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, integration-testing, etl, multiple-instances

I have an sql server and its been installed as new instance called instance2 . Now when i tries to open MSDB folder under stored packages this gives me below error

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The SQL Server instance specified in SSIS service configuration is not present or is not available. This might occur when there is no default instance of SQL Server on the computer. For more information, see the topic "Configuring the Integration Services Service" in %SQL_PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME% Books Online.

Login timeout expired
A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].  (MsDtsSrvr)

------------------------------

Login timeout expired
A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].  (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Also Once i tried to open the package from visual studio it returns the below error

```
TITLE: Add Copy of Existing Package
------------------------------

An OLE DB error 0x80004005 (Login timeout expired) occurred while enumerating packages. A SQL statement was issued and failed.


------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An OLE DB error 0x80004005 (Login timeout expired) occurred while enumerating packages. A SQL statement was issued and failed.


------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

i have two instances: Adventure and instance2 also I added instance name in msdtsrvr.ini  but it didn't fix the issue

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ssis service does not support multiple instances.  SSIS will be configured to managed packages on the first instance installed on the machine or the default instance.  There is some more information about that here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137789.aspx

This applies to versions < 2012.  2012 and up support this storage model for backwards compatibility or you could convert to the project deployment model.

Comment: The issue is solved by editing the xml file. when i  inserted servername and instance name its just fine.